Pass device udid from test parameters to DesiredCapabilities in seperate classes
I have seperate class with called CommonAndroidDriver where capabilites and driver are. I want to be able to add device udid as parameter seperately for each test.
public class CommonAndroidDriver {

    public static AndroidDriver driver;
    private URL serverUrl;
    private DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    public CommonAndroidDriver(ITestContext context) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.serverUrl = new URL("https:");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:platformName", MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appPackage", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appActivity", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:oauthClientId", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:oauthClientSecret", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:tenantId", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:udid", context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("udid"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:autoGrantPermissions", true);

        this.driver = new AndroidDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
    }
    public AndroidDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }
}


Example test start, I want this udid to be entered UP in CommonAndroidDriver:
public class LoginTest extends BaseAppium {

    public LoginTest() throws IOException {
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters({"login", "password", "udid"})
    public void Login(String login, String password, String udid) throws Exception {

        //some test steps

    }
}

I started combining it with ITestContext getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter, but couldn't find a way to pass udid to capabilities.
Testngxml
<suite name="AndroidAppiumTest">
    <test name="LoginTests">
        <parameter name="loginmp" value="test@test.com"/>
        <parameter name="passwordtest" value="Test1234"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="DeviceId"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.LoginTest"/>
            <methods>
                <include name="Login"/>
            </methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

BaseAppium
public class BaseAppium {

    public AndroidDriver driver;


    public BaseAppium() throws IOException {
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        this.driver = new CommonAndroidDriver(context).getDriver();
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setTest() {
    }


    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.driver.terminateApp("app.name");
        this.driver.quit();
    }
}


There are a couple of issues in your code.

The test should not be working with a static instance of AndroidDriver because this can interfere when we run tests in parallel.
We are creating the CommonAndroidDriver at a constructor level in BaseAppium. We should instead be creating it via setup() method.

Here's a cleaned-up code that shows how the fixes/changes would look like
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CommonAndroidDriver {
    // Intentionally using RemoteWebDriver to avoid my test project having to add dependency on appium client
    // just for illustration purposes.
    public RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private final URL serverUrl;

    public CommonAndroidDriver(ITestContext context) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.serverUrl = new URL("https:");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appPackage", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appActivity", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:oauthClientId", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:oauthClientSecret", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("uftm:tenantId", "blabla");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:udid", context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("udid"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:autoGrantPermissions", true);
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(serverUrl, capabilities);
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }
}

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BaseAppium {

    public RemoteWebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        this.driver = new CommonAndroidDriver(context).getDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        this.driver.quit();
    }
}


I edited the changes according to Your advice, but now the I get the: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement.

This is my WaiForElement method and it worked fine before the changes so I assume the null pointer is all about getDriver method?
public void zaczekajNaWidocznoscElementu(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
FluentWait wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
